# Can this PHP code be improved?

Tags: php, string, forms, variables, save

What I'm wanting to achieve is basically setting variables from data entered through my form (these variables are then used throughout my website). I'm not to concerned with security as I'm the only one who would have access to the form.

So at the moment I am using `fwrite` to save the data in separate files and then using `file_get_contents` for each variable. The data from the form is small, one or two words for each field.

I'm unable to use a database so below is an example of what I have working at the moment, can it be improved or is there any other ways of achieving this?

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']))
{
$myFile = "first.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_REQUEST['first'];
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]/", "", $stringData);
fwrite($fh, $string);
fclose($fh);

$myFile_second = "second.php";
$fh2 = fopen($myFile_second, 'w') or die("can't open file2");
$stringData2 = $_REQUEST['second'];
$string2 = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]/", "", $stringData2);
fwrite($fh2, $string2);
fclose($fh2);

$myFile_third = "third.php";
$fh3 = fopen($myFile_third, 'w') or die("can't open file3");
$stringData3 = $_REQUEST['third'];
$string3 = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]/", "", $stringData3);
fwrite($fh3, $string3);
fclose($fh3);
}

$first = file_get_contents ("first.php");
$second = file_get_contents ("second.php");
$third = file_get_contents ("third.php");

?>

<form method="post" name="installer">

<div id="field">
<label>First</label>
<input type="text" name="first" value="<?php echo $first; ?>" />
</div>

<div id="field">
<label>Second</label>
<input type="text" name="second" value="<?php echo $second; ?>" />
</div>

<div id="field">
<label>Third</label>
<input type="text" name="third" value="<?php echo $third; ?>" />
</div>

<div id="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="sub" />
</div>

</form>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated thanks :)

**Update**

Well thank you to everyone for your help and suggestions. I've now implemented something similar to below and I must say it works wonderfully!

```
<?
if (isset($_REQUEST['sub'])) {

    $files_data = array(
        'first' => &$_REQUEST['first'],
        'second' => &$_REQUEST['second'],
        'third' => &$_REQUEST['third']
    );

    $files_data = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]+/", "", $files_data);

    file_put_contents('data.txt', serialize($files_data)) !== FALSE or die("Can't write to file!" . PHP_EOL);
    } 

$files_data = unserialize(file_get_contents('data.txt'));

$first = $files_data[first];
$second = $files_data[second];
$third = $files_data[third];

?>

<form method="post" name="installer">
<div id="field">
<label>First</label>
<input type="text" name="first" value="<?php echo $first; ?>" />
</div>
<div id="field">
<label>Second</label>
<input type="text" name="second" value="<?php echo $second; ?>" />
</div>
<div id="field">
<label>Third</label>
<input type="text" name="third" value="<?php echo $third; ?>" />
</div>
<div id="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="sub" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) and [arrays](http://php.net/array) are what you need here to compact the code. Also use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) rather than fopen/etc. - And please explain why the target files have a .php extension, if they only contain textual data.

Comment: @Jessica, why can you not use a database?

Comment: Maybe this question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.

Comment: hello, what the preg_replace() should fix ? And will the 'first.php', 'second.php' and 'third.php' contents be reused somewhere else in the web site only by other PHP scripts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are doing this for persistence (i.e. the web server reboots and you want your data to be there once it's back up)? So if you are stuck with writing, reading and parsing a multitude of files it's hard to shave massive amounts of time from your execution.

You could look at [fscan](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php) and see if that will make the reading a bit faster for you.

Other than that I recommend that you **cache** the data once you have parsed the files so you don't have to do it over and over and only rescan once the files change. You could keep track of this by a **checksum** or looking at the files **modified** time stamp.

One way to "simplify" it would be to save your posted data in an **array** and **serializing** that and saving it to a file. Then you could read the entire file in one go and **unserialize** it and you would have your array with the data back.

A quick-and-dirty way to save a array to a file would be something like

```
file_put_contents('mydatafile', serialize($myArray)));
```

and to get the array back

```
$myArray = unserialize(file_get_contents('mydatafile'));
```

Comment: Thank you inquam, your ideas are on my to do list and the array storing with serializing definitely sounds useful. You hit the nail on the head with the need for persistence too :P

Answer (score 1):

you can use php sessions to store and retrieve values.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Secondly you can use SplFileInfo instead of fopen , fwrite

```
$myFile = 'foo.txt';
$file = new SplFileInfo($myFile);
$lines = $file->openFile('w');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
<?php

if( isset($_REQUEST['sub']) ){

$files = array(
    'first.php'  => $_REQUEST['first'],
    'second.php' => $_REQUEST['second'],
    'third.php'  => $_REQUEST['third']
);  

foreach($files as $file => $request){
    $fh = fopen($file,'w') or die("can't open file ". $file);
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]/", "", $request);
    fwrite($fh, $string);
    fclose($fh);
}

}

$first = file_get_contents ("first.php");
$second = file_get_contents ("second.php");
$third = file_get_contents ("third.php");

?>
```

But as said above, it's much more efficient to use databases.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function do_file_operation($filename,$field_name)
{
    $myFile = $filename;
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = $_POST[$field_name];
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]/", "", $stringData);
    fwrite($fh, $string);
    fclose($fh);
}


if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{

    do_file_operation("first.php","first");
    do_file_operation("second.php","second");
    do_file_operation("third.php","third");

}

$first = file_get_contents ("first.php");
$second = file_get_contents ("second.php");
$third = file_get_contents ("third.php");

?>

<form method="post" name="installer">

<div id="field">
<label>First</label>
<input type="text" name="first" value="<?php echo $first; ?>" />
</div>

<div id="field">
<label>Second</label>
<input type="text" name="second" value="<?php echo $second; ?>" />
</div>

<div id="field">
<label>Third</label>
<input type="text" name="third" value="<?php echo $third; ?>" />
</div>

<div id="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="sub" />
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
if (isset($_REQUEST['sub'])) {
    # MAKE SURE YOUR FORM IS WELL PROTECTED !
    file_put_contents("first.php",  preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]/", "", $_REQUEST['first']));
    file_put_contents("second.php", preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]/", "", $_REQUEST['second']));
    file_put_contents("third.php", preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]/", "", $_REQUEST['third']));
}    
?>
<form method="post" name="installer">
<div id="field">
<label>First</label>
<input type="text" name="first" value="<?php echo file_get_contents("first.php"); ?>" />
</div>
<div id="field">
<label>Second</label>
<input type="text" name="second" value="<?php echo file_get_contents("second.php"); ?>" />
</div>
<div id="field">
<label>Third</label>
<input type="text" name="third" value="<?php echo file_get_contents("third.php"); ?>" />
</div>
<div id="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="sub" />
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a little modification of @Austin Brunkhorst's code. Sorry, too much to post in comment.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['sub'])) {
    //No need to copy variables
    $files_data = array(
        'first' => &$_REQUEST['first'],
        'second' => &$_REQUEST['second'],
        'third' => &$_REQUEST['third']
    );
    //Note that you should use '+' at the end of match
    //so that preg can match more the one character at once,
    //it is much faster. And we can apply it once to whole array.
    $files_data = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]+/", "", $files_data);
    //Note '&' in foreach to disable variable copying
    foreach ($files_data as $filename => &$request_str) {
        //Why use complex fwrite when we have a ready function to write to file?
        file_put_contents($filename . '.php', $request_str) !== FALSE or die("Can't write to file '$filename'!" . PHP_EOL);
        //We don't need to read files again when we already have our string
        //It is ugly, but fun! Maby this should be avoided :)
        $$filename = $request_str;
    }
} else {
    $first = file_get_contents("first.php");
    $second = file_get_contents("second.php");
    $third = file_get_contents("third.php");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to include the code in your project, you can use [eval](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
$includes = array('first', 'second', 'third');
foreach ($includes as $value) {
    $code = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.:,=?%\/\\s]/", "", $_REQUEST[$value]);
    if (!eval($code))
        die('Parse Error in $_REQUEST["'.$value.'"]');
}
```

As pointed out, this leaves you wide open for any attack, so make sure you *really* secure the script, e.g. with a [.htaccess-file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/de/configuring.html#htaccess).

Comment: As Jessica clearly stated, that she'll secure the whole script in other ways, that is completely okay in this special case. I'll add the hint to my answer anyway.

Comment: It's not really anything about environment, it's a practise you don't want to preach.

Comment: @Pelshoff: I don't know how this code helps with question, but sometimes you have to forget about security and just do something when you have no options. It is stupid to always concern about security when it is already done on another level, if you don't belive me I can give you links to big succesfull projects that do something like this: for example setting cron jobs in web panels etc.

Comment: Exactly - Yes, under normal circumstances, my code would be devastating to security. But if you actually *want* to be able to pass code via a formular into the system (e.g. for a remote shell), you actually *have* to do it that way. And *Of course* you need to secure it externally in that case.